# circular imageview is shrieked to look wierd and textview is cutting words in the middle of the sentence inside Recyclerview row

Tags: android, textview, imageview, scaletype

I have a row item layout that is being inflated by recyclerview.

Inside the row I have 2 elements that are action not as expected - Imageview image comes out constricted and the Textview text is linebreaking words in the middle of them.

For the image I tried to add scaleType="centerCrop" and that did not help

for the textView I added the following -

```
android:breakStrategy="simple"
android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
```

and yet again, did not help.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#b0b3b7"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:tag="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="#b0b3b7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/heroImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/adapterProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroTitle"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:text="Hero Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/heroAbilities"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/heartImageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heroImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heroAbilities"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="25dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="15dp"
            android:breakStrategy="simple"
            android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#444"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heroImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heroTitle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/heartImageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/empty_heart"
            android:tag="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heroTitle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and here is an image of what happens with the image and text -

https://github.com/alonsd/HeroApp/blob/master/HeroAppFront.jpeg

Comment: you have provided static value for CIVs width but you are using wrap_content for height, try using same value for height as well.

Comment: Try to use somethings like this `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in  the `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView`
And here you have a link to read more about `scaleType`
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide